# Asymptotic behaviour of series from QHO

Tags: power-series

In the context of the simple quantum harmonic oscillator, the asymptotic behaviour of the power series expansion of $x^ke^{x^2}$ for some natural number $k$ comes up. From my own work I find that the asymptotic behaviour of the ratio of the coefficients $a_{n+2}/a_n$ should be
$$\frac{n!}{(n+2)!} = \frac{1}{n^2 + 3n + 2}  $$ which is very different than the correct $\frac{2}{n}$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I don't get either of those answers, even after replacing $x^2$ by $\frac{x^2}{2}$. To clarify, you are asking about the asymptotic behavior of the coefficient of $\frac{x^n}{n!}$, as a function of $n$?

Comment: The asymptotic behaviour of the coefficients of the Taylor series of the function first given @QiaochuYuan

Comment: @QiaochuYuan When I put it into Mathematica for terms $n=98$ and $n+2=100$ I get 1/50 as expected from the result I quoted, but I can't seem to get it.

Comment: Why doesn't your answer depend on $k$? For $k = 0$ the coefficient of $\frac{x^{100}}{100!}$ is $\frac{100!}{50!}$ which is much larger than $\frac{1}{50}$. If you meant $e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$ then the coefficient is $\frac{100!}{2^{50} 50!}$ which is still much larger than $\frac{1}{50}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The series expansion is $x^k(1+x^2/1 + x^4/2 + x^8/3! + x^{16}/4!+ \dots)$. I'm not sure where you're getting those expressions for $a_{n+2}/a_n$?

Comment: You didn't say anything about $\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_n}$! I asked whether you were interested in the asymptotic behavior of the coefficients which is a quite different question. Try writing down what you think $a_n$ is first.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm so sorry, I realize now I missed including that as I asked the question on my phone! Will edit now.